# r - how to cancel for loop without losing the data

Tags: r, loops, curl, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping a website. After thousands of iterations the server went down, the system is stuck, and I get the following error:

```
Error in curl::curl(path) : all connections are in use
```

Is there a way of exiting the loop without losing the data I have scraped so far, which is worth one week of downloading?

```
library(rvest)
url <- paste("http://www.example.com",(1:130000))
GNR <- lapply(url,function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  try(list(html_text(html_nodes(read_html(i), "h7")),
       html_text(html_nodes(read_html(i), "#MainContent_IndividualUC_lblBirth"))
  ))
})
```

(Sorry for not providing a reproducible example; if I knew how to recreate the error I wouldn't be posting the question!)

Answer (score 2):

Could you write the scraped data to a file, and append to it, every time you get new data?

```
url <- paste("http://www.example.com",(1:130000))
GNR <- lapply(url,function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  scrapedTmp <- try(list(html_text(html_nodes(read_html(i), "h7")),
           html_text(html_nodes(read_html(i), "#MainContent_IndividualUC_lblBirth"))
  ))
  write(unlist(scrapedTmp), file="path_to-text-file", append=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: This could slow down the execution a lot, but it's a good idea. Rather than appending every iteration, it might make more sense to append, say, every 500 iterations.

Comment: Yeah for example, whatever is most feasible and performant. But anyway better than loosing scraped data of a whole week ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems like a good solution next time I write a similar code. For the time being, however, I need to save the data downloaded so far. Do you know how to force stop the loop without losing it all?

Comment: You could either try using the silent=TRUE argument of try(), so that it will skip errors (which in this case might be problematic, as the connections are all in use, and just skipping it doesnt resolve anything). Or maybe use the tryCatch function and use the error-argument, where you save the already downloaded data? But unfortunately i'm not a big expert on Error handling in R.